# Make a Material UI Component in React Sticky when scrolling (not AppBar)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

So I have AppBar working fine.  And I didn't even use sticky for that but I think I need some kind of sticky style to make my element in the page essentially stick at the top when the user scrolls.  I essentially want this.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

But within my React page I want my `ProgressBar` component to remain at the top. The component below this `RenderTeamSelections` which is a big table, it will push the `ProgressBar` out of view quickly.  I want to kept the `ProgressBar` in view while the user makes selections from the table.  Here is the relevant code.

```
 return (

      <div className={rootClassName}>
        <div className="g-row">
          <div className="g-col">
            <AccountProfile {...this.props} />
            <br />
            <Team team={this.props.team} profileDetail={profileDetail} />
            <br />
            <ProgressBar {...this.props} />
            <br />
            <RenderTeamSelections {...this.props] />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
```

I am familiar with the use of withStyles and have played with some settings on the position of `ProgressBar` like 'fixed', 'sticky' and '-webkit-sticky' but have not gotten it to stick at the top when I scroll yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I didn't see anything Material docs that seemed to directly relate to this scenario.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to get it working with material ui themes

here is my styles.  I added a z-index because my table selects and table header data were still visible in `<RenderTeamSelections {...this.props] />` in the sticky as I scrolled.

Here is the final component with styles.

```
const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        background: 'white',
        position: '-webkit-sticky',
        position: 'sticky',
        top: 20,
        bottom: 20, 
        paddingTop: '40px',
        paddingBottom: '40px',
        zIndex: 5,
    },
    details: {
        display: 'flex'
    },
    progressWrapper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    linearProgress: {
        height: 20
    },
});


export function ProgressBar(props) {
    const { profileDetail, classes } = props;
    const [completeness, setCompleteness] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (profileDetail) {
            setCompleteness(profileDetail.teamKeysTier1.split(",").filter(x => { return x.length != 0 }).length + profileDetail.teamKeysTier2.split(",").filter(x => { return x.length != 0 }).length)
        }
    }, [profileDetail])

    return (
        <Portlet className={classes.root} >
            <PortletContent >
                {completeness > 8 ?
                    <div className={classes.progressWrapper}>
                        <Typography variant="h3" color="textSecondary">Team Selection Completeness: {completeness * 10 + 10}%</Typography>
                        <br /> 
                        <br />
                        <LinearProgress
                            className={classes.linearProgress}
                            value={completeness * 10 + 10}
                            variant="determinate"
                            position="fixed"
                        /> </div> :
                    <div className={classes.progressWrapper}>
                        <Typography variant="h3" color="textSecondary">Team Selection Completeness: {completeness * 10}%</Typography>
                        <br /> 
                        <br />
                        <LinearProgress
                            className={classes.linearProgress}
                            value={completeness * 10}
                            variant="determinate"
                            position="fixed"
                        />
                    </div>}
            </PortletContent>
        </Portlet>

    )

}

export default withStyles(styles)(ProgressBar);
```

Comment: withStyles deprecaded from MUI >=5 src: https://mui.com/system/styles/advanced/

Answer (score 13):

On most components you can add `{position: 'fixed'}`. So try to use it in the component styling. if that doesn't work try to change the zIndex.

Example:

```
<Paper style={{position: 'fixed'}}>
   <List className={classes.list} component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders"
      subheader={<ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">Navigation</ListSubheader>}>
          <ListItem button>
             <ListItemIcon>
               <SubjectIcon/>
             </ListItemIcon>
             <ListItemText primary="Overview" />
          </ListItem>
  </List>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Material UI AppBar component with the position="stick" property.

```
<AppBar position="sticky"></AppBar>
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#fixed-placement