# Material-UI Vertical tabs hidden by Grid Contents

Tags: css, material-ui

When I add grid and grid items, the vertical tabs get covered like this: [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTQW7.png), I want the contents to achieve this: [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6fET.png). Any help would be so greatly appreciated! I just started with Material UI.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Box, Grid, Tab, Tabs, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Product from "../components/Product";

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`vertical-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`vertical-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `vertical-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `vertical-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    display: "flex",
    height: 500,
  },
  tabs: {
    borderRight: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
  },
  productsContainer: {
    paddingTop: "20px",
    paddingLeft: "50px",
    paddingRight: "50px",
    margin: "auto",
  },
}));

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  //UI
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Tabs
          orientation="vertical"
          variant="scrollable"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
          className={classes.tabs}
        >
          <Tab label="All Items" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Hand" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Skin" {...a11yProps(2)} />
          <Tab label="Face" {...a11yProps(3)} />
          <Tab label="Body" {...a11yProps(4)} />
          <Tab label="Fragrance" {...a11yProps(5)} />
          <Tab label="Home" {...a11yProps(6)} />
        </Tabs>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
          <Grid container spacing={4} className={classes.productsContainer}>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={10} md={6} lg={4} key={product._id}>
                <Product product={product} />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
          Item Two
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
          Item Three
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
          Item Four
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={4}>
          Item Five
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={5}>
          Item Six
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={6}>
          Item Seven
        </TabPanel>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: If you can create a demo using CodeSandbox, I can help.

Comment: Thank you very much, here is the link to the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/red-dew-ugttc

Comment: You can add an attribute `overflow: visible` to Tabs styles: https://q3bpo.csb.app/

Comment: @m4n0 do you know how I can make the side tabs fixed in location so when I scroll up and down the side bars stay fixed like how https://material-ui.com/api/accordion/  is?

Comment: You can try one of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136853/make-a-material-ui-component-in-react-sticky-when-scrolling-not-appbar